# Laravel - 500 Internal Server Error on POSTMAN

Tags: laravel, api

I have written my API in Laravel on Local Server and it worked perfectly when I testing the endpoints on in POSTMAN.  However, when I moved it to the online server and tested it on POSTMAN, I got this error:

> 500 Internal Server Error

This is the detail error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `users` where `email` = med@gmail.com limit 1) in file /home/medly/public_html/medly/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 664

I have check the connection, there is no problem

I expect the GET to give me the result but it throws error.  What do I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your connection if you have "localhost" replace to "127.0.0.1", check the port where you are trying to connect 3306 is the default maybe you have installed in another port.